# H265 10 bit to H264 8 bit through NVENC looks terrible

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video, video-encoding, h.264

I'm currently using FFMPEG run with Sickbeard Mp4 Automator to convert H265 video to H264 since my phone chugs hard playing H265 10 bitvideo. I set it to use NVENC and it's unnoticeable for brighter shows, but I'm noticing terrible pixelly areas when I started watching Steins;Gate, which has a lot more dark scenes compared to what I usually watch. For comparison, here's an image of what I notice.

Compare the space to the left of her head

[image: Look at the spot next to her head, lots of that pixelly stuff]

I can run everything through software as h264 10-bit by setting sickbeard mp4 automator/ffmpeg to use `pix-fmt=yuv420p10le` and it looks fine, but it takes too damn long, and more importantly my phone struggles to play the files. Is there a better way? I don't know about the other guy but I can see the pixelation in two monitors.

Comment: Of course, the images you posted are 8-bit too & look virtually identical to me, viewing on an 8-bit screen, even though it is fully-calibrated. The 264 looks very slightly more jagged-edged, but not enough that would bother me. The image is pretty small anyway, so that's going to make it look worse, as you're at pixel-peeking levels to see that.

Comment: You'd have to look at it zoomed in full screen to notice it, which is coincidentally what I'm doing with my phone while I'm watching it.

Comment: Well, I was looking at it on a 27" screen, zoomed variously right up to individual pixel-level… the difference is my display is calibrated. Apparently your uncalibrated display is having a tougher time of it. You will alway get some banding in 8-bit, it's unavoidable, but I'm not really seeing it here.

Comment: Banding was an incorrect term, as you said I'm noticing jagged edges in light to dark transitions. Not familiar with the correct term. I don't notice it when I'm watching the 10 bit source even if my display's just 8 bit.

Comment: Maybe you need some dither filtering?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. What's dither filtering?

Comment: @Beefmaster5000BCE "Noise shaping" *might* be what you need to experiment with.

Comment: I don't know what that is either, is that something you enable in ffmpeg?